# How to summarize(n=n()) with different filter()?

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I want to print the following tables.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x35sV.png)
I tried several ways but I can only add one of the columns (either "to_ORD" or "to_MDW") with information of that type. How can I code to get them at the same time and on the same table?

This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights13)
flights_1 <- flights %>%
    group_by(carrier) %>%
    filter(dest == "ORD") %>%
    summarize(to_ORD = n())
flights_1
flights_2 <- flights %>%
    group_by(carrier) %>%
    filter(dest == "MDW") %>%
    summarize(to_MDW = n())
flights_2
```

I also tried: (not correct obviously)

```
flights_1 <- flights %>%
    group_by(carrier) %>%
    filter(dest == "ORD"| dest == "MDW") %>%
    summarize(to_ORD = n())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `carrier` calculate count of `'ORD'` and `'MDW'` values and keep only those rows where any value is greater than 0.

```
library(dplyr)

flights %>%
  group_by(carrier) %>%
  summarize(to_ORD = sum(dest == "ORD"), 
            to_MDW = sum(dest == "MDW")) %>%
  filter(to_ORD > 0 | to_MDW > 0)

#  carrier to_ORD to_MDW
#  <chr>    <int>  <int>
#1 9E        1056      0
#2 AA        6059      0
#3 B6         905      0
#4 EV           2      0
#5 MQ        2276      0
#6 OO           1      0
#7 UA        6984      0
#8 WN           0   4113
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines, but more steps to illustrate reasoning, which is eliminating unnecessary data then distinguishing between the two Chicago-area airports.

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)
flights %>% 
  filter(dest == "ORD" | dest == "MDW") %>%
  group_by(carrier,dest) %>%
  count() %>%
  mutate(to_ORD = ifelse(dest == "ORD", n,0),
         to_MDW = ifelse(dest == "MDW",n,0)) %>%
  select(-dest,-n)
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `dest`
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   carrier, dest [8]
#>   dest  carrier to_ORD to_MDW
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 ORD   9E        1056      0
#> 2 ORD   AA        6059      0
#> 3 ORD   B6         905      0
#> 4 ORD   EV           2      0
#> 5 ORD   MQ        2276      0
#> 6 ORD   OO           1      0
#> 7 ORD   UA        6984      0
#> 8 MDW   WN           0   4113
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyr)
flights %>% 
  select(carrier, dest) %>% 
  filter(dest %in% c("ORD", "MDW")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = dest, values_from = dest, 
      values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  carrier   ORD   MDW
#  <chr>   <int> <int>
#1 UA       6984     0
#2 AA       6059     0
#3 MQ       2276     0
#4 B6        905     0
#5 WN          0  4113
#6 9E       1056     0
#7 OO          1     0
#8 EV          2     0
```

---

Or using `base R` with `table` and `subset`

```
table(subset(flights, dest %in% c("ORD", "MDW"), select = c(carrier, dest)))
```